# Prove that the sum to n terms of the sequence Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm not quite sure what this question is asking and I don't know how to start the proof for it. Do I need to make my own summation? not really sure.

Prove that the sum  to n terms of the Sequence:

$$\frac{1^2}{1\times3},\frac{2^2}{3\times5},\frac{3^2}{5\times7},...$$

is $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2(2n+1)}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use induction.  For the induction step, simplify
$$ \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2(2n+1)} - \dfrac{(n-1)n}{2(2n-1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1^2}{1\times3}+\frac{2^2}{3\times5}+\frac{3^2}{5\times7}+\cdots+\frac{n^2}{(2n-1)\times(2n+1)}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2(2n+1)}$$
Seems like a perfect candidate for an induction proof. Establish the base case ($n=1$), then show that if the sum holds for $n=k$, then it holds for $n=k+1$.

Comment: ok I got it to the point of n=k+1 but I'm stuck and I don't know where to substitute the n=k back into the equation to prove the statement

Answer (score 1):

For fun, suppose we don't use induction.

First we simplify the terms of the sequence. Using long division, we see that

$$\dfrac{k^2}{(2k-1)(2k+1)} = \dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1/4}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}$$

Then using partial fraction decomposition on the second term, we reach

$$\dfrac{k^2}{(2k-1)(2k+1)} = \dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{8(2k - 1)}- \dfrac{1}{8(2 k + 1)}$$

Now sum from $k=1$ to $n$, and notice the nice telescoping effect.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{k^2}{(2k - 1)(2k + 1)} &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{8(2k - 1)} - \dfrac{1}{8(2 k + 1)}\\
&= \dfrac{n}{4} + \dfrac{1}{8}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{2k - 1} - \dfrac{1}{2 k + 1} \right)\\
&= \dfrac{n}{4} + \dfrac{1}{8}\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{2 n + 1}\right) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{8}\left(2n + \dfrac{2n}{2 n + 1}\right) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{8}\left(\dfrac{4n^2 + 4n}{2 n + 1}\right) \\
&= \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2(2n+1)} 
\end{align}$$